# How to cut out first 5 seconds with youtube_dl and ffmpeg in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

i have a python script to download and save a MP3 and i would like to add code to cut out 5 seconds from the beginning of the MP3.

```
def download():
    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'outtmpl': 'c:/MP3/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
        'cookiefile': 'cookies.txt',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([inpYTLinkSong.get()])
```

I found some code for command line to cut x seconds:

`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:15.00 -i "OUTPUT-OF-FIRST URL" -t 00:00:10.00 -c copy out.mp4`

So i think i have to get the -ss part into the postprocessor part in my script, something like:

```
'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
        'ss':'00:00:05.00'
    }],
```

But of course its not working with 'ss' or 'duration' (found in ffmpeg docu).

So any ideas what i have to put there instead of 'ss'?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [postprocessor_args](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L316) like this:

```
'postprocessor_args': '-ss 00:00:05'
```

If the input is not live it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It's working with

```
'postprocessor_args': ['-ss', '00:00:05']
```

Thanks @pszemus for the direction.